# Claim-check with Service Bus - node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I want implement the claim-check workflow with Azure Service Bus:
[claim check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check)

Is it possible to do that using node.js?
I just found only .net examples and I cant see anything in @azure/service-bus node package that seems to refer to claim check.

Anyone that had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A claim check pattern can be implemented using any language as long as there's support to hook into the pipeline. For a long time, this pattern was not easy not possible to implement with .NET either as the previous .NET SDK did not provide a way to hook into the sending/receiving. The new .NET SDK had that consideration from the beginning. [Almost](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/106). Once it was implemented, claim-check pattern implementation was a no brainer.

If you're looking to implement a claim check pattern as a plugin, it would need to have a pipeline concept support in the [Node.js SDK.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/serviceBus/README.md). You can [raise an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc%20label%3A%22Service%20Bus%22) for the Service Bus library to request it or contribute yourself.

Another alternative is to abstract sending and receiving operations with your custom implementation that would use some kind of storage for the payloads.